# Siamese networks: Why does the network to be duplicated?

Tags: facebook, neural-network, conv-neural-network, metrics, face-recognition

The DeepFace paper from Facebook uses a Siamese network to learn a metric. They say that the DNN that extracts the 4096 dimensional face embedding has to be duplicated in a Siamese network, but both duplicates share weights. But if they share weights, every update to one of them will also change the other. So why do we need to duplicate them?

Why can't we just apply one DNN to two faces and then do backpropagation using the metric loss? Do they maybe mean this and just talk about duplicated networks for "better" understanding?

Quote from the paper:

> We  have  also  tested  an  end-to-end  metric  learning  ap-
>   proach, known as Siamese network [8]:  once learned, the
>   face  recognition  network  (without  the  top  layer)  is  repli-
>   cated twice (one for each input image) and the features are
>   used to directly predict whether the two input images be-
>   long to the same person. This is accomplished by: a) taking
>   the absolute difference between the features, followed by b)
>   a top fully connected layer that maps into a single logistic
>   unit (same/not same).  The network has roughly the same
>   number of parameters as the original one, since much of it
>   is shared between the two replicas, but requires twice the
>   computation.  Notice that in order to prevent overfitting on
>   the face verification task,  we enable training for only the
>   two topmost layers.

Paper: https://research.fb.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/deepface-closing-the-gap-to-human-level-performance-in-face-verification.pdf

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is that yes, I think that looking at the architecture of the network will help you understand what is going on. You have two networks that are "joined at the hip" i.e. sharing weights. That's what makes it a "Siamese network". The trick is that you want the two images you feed into the network to pass through the same embedding function. So to ensure that this happens both branches of the network need to share weights.

Then we combine the two embeddings into a metric loss (called "contrastive loss" in the image below). And we can back-propagate as normal, we just have two input branches available so that we can feed in two images at a time.

I think a picture is worth a thousand words. So check out how a Siamese network is constructed (at least conceptually) below.

[image: A Siamese Network Architecture]

Comment: I was actually going to ask "why the name Siamese Neural Network?" but this question answers it already (Siamese from "Siamese Twins" i.e. Conjoined twins sharing common parts, in case of Siamese Network  it is sharing common weights). Thanks for the clear explanation.

Comment: What would be the differece between feeding input_1 and input_2 to the same embedding? I don't get why there is two replicated networks, if they are the same, would not one be enough?

Comment: There isn't any difference. The trick that is going on here is that by having 2 branches I can feed two images to the network at the sme time. I want to be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The gradients depend on the activation values. So for each branch gradients will be different and final update could be based on some averaging to share the weights